# on-Isomorphism of Alternating Group $A_n$ as a Composition Factor in Composition Series of $\mathrm{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / p^t \mathbb{Z}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

For $q \in \mathbb{N}$ let $\Gamma(q)=\operatorname{ker}\left(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z} / q \mathbb{Z})\right)$

Prove that the Alternating group $A_n$, for $n \geq 7$ is not isomorphic to any composition factor in a composition series of $\mathrm{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / p^t \mathbb{Z}\right)$.

Please let me know if my answer is correct and if not, please let me know the mistake.

Solution:
To prove that the alternating group $A_n$, for $n \geq 7$, is not isomorphic to any composition factor in a composition series of $\mathrm{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / p^t \mathbb{Z}\right)$, we will first show that $A_n$ is simple for $n \geq 7$. Then, we will analyze the possible composition factors of $\mathrm{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / p^t \mathbb{Z}\right)$ and show that none of them can be isomorphic to $A_n$.

1. $A_n$ is simple for $n \geq 7$.

This is a well-known result in group theory. The proof is not too difficult, but it is somewhat involved. The main idea is to show that any nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ of $A_n$ must contain a 3-cycle, and since the 3-cycles generate $A_n$, it follows that $N = A_n$. Thus, $A_n$ is simple.

2. Analyzing the composition factors of $\mathrm{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / p^t \mathbb{Z}\right)$.

Let $G = \mathrm{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / p^t \mathbb{Z}\right)$. We know that $G$ is a finite group and its order is given by $|G| = p^t(p^t - 1)(p^{t-1} + 1)$. Now, let's consider a composition series of $G$:

$$\{1\} = G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft G_n = G$$

The composition factors are the quotient groups $G_i / G_{i-1}$, and by Jordan-Hölder theorem, they are unique up to isomorphism. We will now analyze the possible composition factors of $G$.

(a) If $p$ is odd, then the group $G$ has a unique (up to isomorphism) non-abelian simple group of order $p(p^2 - 1)$ as a composition factor, which is isomorphic to $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. This is because the derived subgroup of $G$ is $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$, and its quotient by the center is $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$. Note that $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has order $p(p^2 - 1)/2$, which is not divisible by $n!$ for $n \geq 7$. Therefore, $A_n$ cannot be isomorphic to this composition factor.

(b) If $p = 2$, then the group $G$ has a unique (up to isomorphism) non-abelian simple group of order $2^t(2^t - 1)$ as a composition factor, which is isomorphic to $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{2^t})$. This is because the derived subgroup of $G$ is $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{2^t})$, and its quotient by the center is $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{2^t})$. Note that $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{F}_{2^t})$ has order $2^t(2^t - 1)/2$, which is not divisible by $n!$ for $n \geq 7$. Therefore, $A_n$ cannot be isomorphic to this composition factor.

The remaining composition factors of $G$ are cyclic groups of prime order. Since $A_n$ is non-abelian and simple for $n \geq 7$, it cannot be isomorphic to any of these cyclic groups.

In conclusion, the alternating group $A_n$, for $n \geq 7$, is not isomorphic to any composition factor in a composition series of $\mathrm{SL}_2\left(\mathbb{Z} / p^t \mathbb{Z}\right)$.

Comment: $A_n$ is simple for $n \ge \color{red}{5}$ : see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2204967/305862) for example.

Comment: @JeanMarie That isn't a mistake though, is it? In fact the argument does not work for $n = 5$ since $A_5$ is isomorphic to $PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ so step 2(a) would break down. The argument does look reasonably kosher to me.

Comment: I understand and it is interesting. Nevertheless, it would be good to insert in your question the explanation you just gave in your comment because of the historical importance of the result for $n=5$ (connection with the impossibility to have "formulas" for the resolution of the general 5th degree equation).